# Is it possible to show/hide a message based on a boolean variable in toastr .js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, toastr

I am using [toastr](https://codeseven.github.io/toastr/) to show a message to my users, I want the message to appear/disappear depending on a boolean value (i.e. content loaded) - Is this possible?

Comment: @ayushgp I'm completely happy with toastrjs, but thanks anyway!

Comment: is your problem solved ??